# Find merge arrows pointing to a version in ClearCase

Tags: scripting, merge, clearcase

I want to find all the merge arrows pointing to a certain version in a script. When I describe the version of the element with the following command:

```
ct describe filename@@/main/some_branch/3
```

I get in the result the following:

```
Hyperlinks:
  Merge <- filename@@/main/other_branch/2
```

I want `ct describe` to output only the relevant information to be used in my script, ie. the versions where the merge arrows come from. In my case, the output should look simply like this:

```
filename@@/main/other_branch/2
```

I didn't find any relevant parameters in the `-fmt` from the man page. Is there any way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option in the [`fmt_ccase` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) would be

```
%[hlink:filter]p
```

> Displays the hyperlink source and target, with an arrow pointing from the source to the target. The optional H argument lists only the hyperlink names.
>   You can optionally specify a filter string, preceded by a colon. This filter if present, restricts the output to names that match the filter string. Case is considered when matching the string.

If this doesn't work, you have to resort to `grep`/`awk` commands in order to extract those version from the `cleartool describe` output.

The `cleartool descr -ahlink` restricts a bit the output.

```
–ahlink
```

> The listing includes the path names of the objects hyperlinked to pname, annotated with → (listed object is the to- object) or ← (listed object is the from-object).
>
> For example:

```
-> M:\gamma\vob1\proj\include\db.c@@\main\52 <- M:\gamma\vob1\proj\bin\vega@@\main\5
```

---

Beside the full script option, you can have a look at external third-party tools like [R&D Reporter](http://www.gomidjets.com/rnd-reporter.php), which can vizualize *and export* those same hyperlinks.
However:

- this is a commercial tool
- depending on the export output and what you want, you might end up parsing just another output to extract what you need.

For more on that tool, contact [Tamir Gefen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138479/tamir-gefen).