# How to find all branches merged to particular branch

Tags: version-control, clearcase, cleartool

I need to list all branches merged to branch of a particular name. Is it possible in Clearcase?

Comment: Does my answer address your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClearCase does not reason in term of branch alone, always in term of *file*.

You could list branches merged to a particular branch for a given *file*.
The only way to generalize that to a group of files would be in UCM with UCM components (group of files) and their baselines (UCM labels), which can be delivered (merged) to an UCM stream (branch)

But in base CC, you would need to:

- list each version of a file (see "[ClearCase: How do I find which version I branched off from?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36484313/6309)", with [`cleartool lsvtree`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsvtree.htm).
  The last segment in the extended path would be the name of the branch (just before the version number).
  See:
- "[ClearCase View and Branch explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36633877/6309)" for definition,
- "[Is ClearCase path is a standard one — '`@@`' and string after that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31424471/6309)" for illustration.
- and then look for an hyperlink (ahlink) as I did in "[Find merge arrows pointing to a version in ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14335333/6309)" in order to detect a merge back to the current branch.