# How do I undo mergeouts on a branch in clearcase?

Tags: merge, clearcase

## Background

I am in a situation where in order to promote code cleanly, views with a certain number have to be branched in a coordinated way as such:

```
/some/dir/here@@/main/dev/view_dev__456_textDescription
/some/dir/here/file.txt@@/main/dev/view_dev__456_textDescription
/some/dir/here@@/main/dev/prod1/view_prod1_dev__456_textDescription
/some/dir/here/file.txt@@/main/dev/prod1/view_prod1_dev__456_textDescription
```

Each view of a certain product must be branched from its product branch.

## Problem

I am in a situation where I accidentally created a product specific view, but off of the dev branch.  Below is the situation I am in:

```
/some/dir/here@@/main/dev/view_dev__456_textDescription
/some/dir/here/file.txt@@/main/dev/view_dev__456_textDescription
/some/dir/here@@/main/dev/view_prod1_dev__456_textDescription <-- The erroneous branch
/some/dir/here/file.txt@@/main/dev/prod1/view_prod1_dev__456_textDescription
```

## Attempted solution

I tried this command to get rid of the erroneous branch:

```
ct rmbranch /some/dir/here@@/main/dev/view_prod1_dev__456_textDescription
```

But I got this error:

```
...
Checking for mergeouts on branch [view_prod1_dev__456_textDescription] ...
ERROR: Cannot delete a WI branch that has mergeouts
cleartool: Warning: Trigger "TRG_PRE_RMBRANCH" has refused to let rmbranch proceed.
cleartool: Error: Unable to remove branch "/some/dir/here@@/main/dev/view_prod1_dev__456_textDescription"
```

Based on the error, I need to get rid of the mergeouts for this branch. Thus my question...

## Question

How do I undo the mergeouts of a specific clearcase branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming base ClearCase here, you do a a `ct lstree --graph` on some file to see if they are merged to other branch version.

That is: check if you see a red arrow, as seen in "[Find all unmerged files/elements in ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7464236/6309)".
That answer includes a cleartool find which would give you all the merged elements between two branches.

For each element version involve in that merge (again, assuming base ClearCase), you  can:

- [describe that version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14334919/6309) and find the merge hyperlink coming from it.
- do a `cleartool rmhlink Merge@xxxxx@/vobs/yourvob`, removing said hyperlink.

Once there is no more merge hyperlink from `view_prod1_dev__456_textDescription`, the `TRG_PRE_RMBRANCH` should not block the `rmbranch` anymore.

See [`cleartool rmhlink`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmhlink.htm), and the previous question: "[How do I search for specific kinds of merge hyperlinks in ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57911275/6309)".

Comment: My thought is that the OP needs to contact their CC admins make sure that this is really acceptable based on their processes. You *can* do that, but if this is a heavily regulated industry, removing development history may cause problems with regulatory audits. You may also find that the rmhlink operations are blocked by triggers.

Comment: @BrianCowan I agree: anything involving `rmver` or `rmhlink` needs to be vetted carefully.